# Create an address bar to direct an iframe?

Tags: iframe

Well, I'm trying to dart back and forth around the internet, in a fashion similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Muimi/gm7gv/.  Unfortunately, my code doesn't work.  What is happening is that the page isn't redirecting at all.  I noticed that it gave me errors like 'page does not exist', for google.com (which exists, just so everyone knows).  So, any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#showUrl {
border:2px solid #0A9;
height:90%;
width:95%;
}
#url {
width:30em;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadUrl() {
    var url = document.getElementById( 'url' ).value;
    var showUrl = document.getElementById( 'showUrl' );
    showUrl.src = url;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Enter URL to load: <input type="text" id="url" />
    <input type="button" value="Load URL" onclick="loadUrl()" />
</form>
<iframe id="showUrl"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including 'http://'? If not, the iframe is trying to load a relative path instead of an absolute path.

```
function loadUrl() {
    var url = document.getElementById( 'url' ).value,
        showUrl = document.getElementById( 'showUrl' );
    showUrl.src = /$https?:\/\//.test(url) ? url : 'http://'+url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does works. I tried it on JsBin and it did work with my website's URL but didn't with Google's

http://jsbin.com/akugeg/1/edit

There can be three reasons:

1. You need to add a protocol so it works as an absolute URL not a
   relative one.
2. Most code debugging services doesn't allow to load iframes, as it itself uses iframe to display the content - for security reasons.
3. Some websites don't like to be loaded in iframes so they just configure their servers to not to load other inside an iframe on other than their own domain.

But I can assure you that the code works and if you try it on your localhost it might work.

Comment: the example url (google) applies to reason 3.  However, you would get an "'X-FRAME-OPTIONS' set to 'SAMEORIGIN'" error instead of "page does not exist"